# activeMQ consumed by logstash (with stomp)

Tags: activemq-classic, logstash

I am using logstash to consume messages in activeMQ,  and I need to use "stomp" to make logstash support activeMQ.  In my activeMQ config file "activeMQ.xml",  I already have the following line in "" part

```
<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

and on the logstash side, in my logstash config file,  I have this:

```
input {
  stomp {  
    password => "admin"
    user => "admin"
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "C:\logstash\cosumedfromstomp.txt"
  }
}
```

which gives error :

```
C:\logstash>rem java -jar logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar agent -f logstash-indexer.conf -- web --backend elasticsearch://127.0.0.1/volarb

C:\logstash>java -cp c:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic logstash.runner agent -f logstash-indexer.conf
Exception in thread "LogStash::Runner" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (InvalidLocaleData) can not load translations from file:C:/logstash/locales/en.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - file:C:/logstash/locales/en.yml>
        at RUBY.load_yml(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:180)
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.__send__(org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1683)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2107)
        at RUBY.load_file(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:161)
        at RUBY.load_translations(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
        at RUBY.load_translations(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15)
        at RUBY.init_translations(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:57)
        at RUBY.lookup(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:71)
        at RUBY.translate(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:26)
        at RUBY.translate(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n.rb:156)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.catch(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1174)
        at RUBY.translate(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/i18n-0.6.4/lib/i18n.rb:152)
        at RUBY.validate_check_required_parameter_names(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/mixin.rb:233)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.each(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1257)
        at RUBY.validate_check_required_parameter_names(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/mixin.rb:225)
        at RUBY.validate(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/mixin.rb:174)
        at RUBY.config_init(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/mixin.rb:52)
        at RUBY.initialize(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/inputs/base.rb:67)
        at RUBY.parse_config(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/agent.rb:333)
        at RUBY.parse(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/file.rb:53)
        at RUBY.each(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/file.rb:91)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
        at RUBY.each(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/file.rb:90)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.each(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1257)
        at RUBY.each(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/file.rb:83)
        at RUBY.parse(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/config/file.rb:39)
        at RUBY.parse_config(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/agent.rb:323)
        at RUBY.run_with_config(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/agent.rb:427)
        at org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex.synchronize(org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149)
        at RUBY.run_with_config(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/agent.rb:426)
        at RUBY.run(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/logstash/agent.rb:373)
        at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:249)
        at RUBY.initialize(C:/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-monolithic/gems/stud-0.0.13/lib/stud/task.rb:12)
```

If I consume from my rabbitMQ, with the following logstash config file, it works:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => "volarb-amqp"
    queue => "elasticsearch"
    key => "elasticsearch"
    exchange => "elasticsearch"
    type => "all"
    durable => true
    auto_delete => false
    exclusive => false
    format => "json_event"
    debug => false
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "C:\logstash\cosumedfromstomp.txt"
  }
}
```

My question is about how to make activeMQ(stomp) part working:
1,  do I need "queue => "elasticsearch" "   in my input part;
2,  anyone has an example for logstash to consume from one queue in acitveMQ (with stomp plubin)?

here is link to use stomp:
http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/stomp
http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to upgrade to a more recent release of logstash than version 1.1.13, particularly with regard to stomp which was beta as of that release.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515951/logstash-with-activemq-stomp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not put in your host, even though it is supposed to default to localhost it says in the docs it's a required attribute. Below is what I have, logstash 1.5

```
stomp {
    destination   => "/topic/topic.name"
    codec         => "json"
    host          => "mq.company.com"
    type          => "mq_message" 
}
```

If that's not enough try adding the rubydebug output & send it to stdout so you can see what's going on in real time.