# logstash with activeMQ/stomp

Tags: activemq-classic, logstash

all.

I am using logstash-1.4.2 to consume messages stored in my activeMQ(with stomp plubgin).

in my acitveMQ.xml  config file, I have the line:

```
<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

when I run my logstash, I have this error:

```
C:\logstash\logstash-1.4.2\bin>logstash agent -f logstashconfig.conf
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| An unexpected error occurred. This is probably a bug.   |
| You can find help with this problem in a few places:    |
|                                                         |
| * chat: #logstash IRC channel on freenode irc.          |
|     IRC via the web: http://goo.gl/TI4Ro                |
| * email: logstash-users@googlegroups.com                |
| * bug system: https://logstash.jira.com/                |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
The error reported is:
  Couldn't find any input plugin named 'stomp'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the stomp input plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/inputs/stomp
```

in my logstashconfig.conf, I have :

```
input {
  stomp {  
    password => "admin"
    user => "admin"
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "C:\logstash\logstash-1.4.2\cosumedfromstomp.txt"
  }
}
```

If I consume from  rabbitMQ, with the following logstashconfig.conf, it would be correct (here is my rabbitMQ version of config):

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => "amqp"
    queue => "elasticsearch"
    key => "elasticsearch"
    exchange => "elasticsearch"
    type => "all"
    durable => true
    auto_delete => false
    exclusive => false
    format => "json_event"
    debug => false
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "C:\logstash\logstash-1.4.2\cosumedfromstomp.txt"
  }
}
```

I don't have trouble with my rabbitMQ version of logstash, the text file created looks correct.

My question is :

1,  do I configure my stomp input wrong?  since I don't have the "queue" name in my config, it might be wrong?
2,  or if the problem is I didn't create the stomp plugin correctly, if that is the reason, it would not be about logstash...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Contributed Plugins. These have been removed from the core download for Logstash. The Stomp plugin is located in the contributed plugins:

> **Stomp**
>
> Milestone: 2
>
> This is a community-contributed plugin! It does not ship with logstash
>   by default, but it is easy to install! To use this, you must have
>   installed the contrib plugins package.

Directions here:

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/contrib-plugins

Hosted on GitHub here:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-contrib